# strtotime returns incorrect timestamp for '-1 month'

Tags: php, date

I've using CCK date field. strtotime at end of Mart (>=29 Mar) will return incorrect result for strtotime('1- month').

```
// Current date Mar 30
$time = strtotime('-1 month');
print date('m/d/Y', $time);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is not a Drupal issue, it is relevant to all of PHP.

Comment: While using the date() function isn't Drupal-specific, it is important to note, that for most uses within Drupal, one should use the format_date() function (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date) so that timezones and other Drupal-specific configurations are taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

This is counter intuitive, but:

```
03/30/2011 - 1 month = 02/30/2011 => 03/02/2011
```

For the same reason:

```
03/31/2011 + 1 month = 04/31/2011 => 05/01/2011
```

There is no way I know of to get "same day last / next month" using the [relative date/time formats of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: but 'previous month' also returns incorrect result. no way to set default value in CCK date field ;( google is silent too

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function report_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case AUTO_REPORT_NODE_FORM:
      // Fix bug with strtotime('-1 month')
      $currentYear  = date('Y');
      $currentMonth = date('n');
      if($currentMonth == 1){
        $relevantMonth = 12;
        $relevantYear = $currentYear -1;
      }
      else{
        $relevantMonth = $currentMonth - 1;
        $relevantYear = $currentYear;
      }
      $form['field_datestamp'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime($relevantYear .'-'. $relevantMonth));
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with drupal but you could use something like:

```
min(date('t'), date('d')); // would yield 28 on March 30th
```

to give you the day last month and if it exceeded the total number of days, ex Feb 30th it would go back down using the min function min (28).